# При смене ConstraintLayout на RelativeLayout перестает запускаться приложение

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

В строке `<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" я все заменил на RelativeLayout` как и рекомендовали на форуме, но теперь перестало запускаться приложение. Я просто хотел вывести надпись привет мир на своем телефоне, используя RelativeLayout и не вышло. Как использовать RelativeLayout и LinearLayout?

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.relative.RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.party.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/s" />

</android.support.relative.RelativeLayout>
```

logcat:

```
02-05 15:20:22.912 12661-12661/com.example.party E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.party, PID: 12661
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.party/com.example.party.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.relative.RelativeLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3160)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.relative.RelativeLayout
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.party.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.relative.RelativeLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.party-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:578)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.party.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6609) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3275) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1744) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7007) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.relative.RelativeLayout
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 22 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: пишите `RelativeLayout` без `android.support.relative`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Классы  `RelativeLayout` и `LinearLayout` находятся в API Android (а не в подключаемой библиотеке, как `ConstraintLayout`) и им не нужно указывать полный импорт в XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.example.party.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/s" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Чтобы избежать подобных ошибок, используйте визуальный редактор для компоновки экрана - он сам подставит нужное в разметку

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало!